How can I use Python Polars to stream the contents of a Parquet file as CSV text to standard output?
Using Python Polars, how can I modify the following script to stream the contents of a Parquet file as CSV text to standard output?
import polars as pl
import sys
pl.scan_parquet("BTCUSDT-trades-2022-01.parquet").sink_csv(sys.stdout)

Python complains that Lazyframe.sink_csv expects a string argument and not a TextIOWrapper:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/storage/Data/Binance/Market Data/Polars/select_btcusdt_aggtrades.py", line 4, in <module>
    pl.scan_parquet("../BTCUSDT/2022/BTCUSDT-trades-2022-01.parquet").sink_csv(sys.stdout)
  File "/home/derek/.cache/uv/archive-v0/bOaA51uU_dQEF2peOOxqI/lib/python3.12/site-packages/polars/_utils/unstable.py", line 58, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/derek/.cache/uv/archive-v0/bOaA51uU_dQEF2peOOxqI/lib/python3.12/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py", line 2717, in sink_csv
    path=normalize_filepath(path),
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/derek/.cache/uv/archive-v0/bOaA51uU_dQEF2peOOxqI/lib/python3.12/site-packages/polars/_utils/various.py", line 225, in normalize_filepath
    path = os.path.expanduser(path)  # noqa: PTH111
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen posixpath>", line 259, in expanduser
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper

Note that I wish to stream the Parquet file and not read the entire file into a DataFrame in memory because each input file is quite large and there are twelve files for each year, so reading all of the the input data for a year would quickly consume all available memory in my laptop.
Data Source
BTCUSDT-trades-2022-01.zip contains the trades in CSV format between Bitcoin and USDT on the Binance cryptocurrency exchange in January 2022.  BTCUSDT-trades-2022-01.parquet contains this trade data in Parquet format.

While not an ideal solution since it won't work in Windows, as a workaround, I modified the script to stream the CSV text to named pipe output.csv which I created in Linux using command mkfifo output.csv.  In another shell process, cat output.csv streams the output to standard output.
# select_trades_btcusdt.py
import polars as pl
import sys
pl.scan_parquet("BTCUSDT-trades-2022-01.parquet").sink_csv("output.csv")

$ uv --quiet run --with polars select_trades_btcusdt.py 2>/dev/null &
[1] 98800
$ cat output.csv | head
trade_id,price,qty,quote_qty,time,is_buyer_maker,is_best_match
1207691977,46216.93,0.00709000,327.67803370,1640995200000,false,true
1207691978,46216.92,0.00041000,18.94893720,1640995200000,true,true
1207691979,46216.93,0.00056000,25.88148080,1640995200000,false,true
1207691980,46216.92,0.00066000,30.50316720,1640995200000,true,true
1207691981,46216.92,0.00523000,241.71449160,1640995200002,true,true
1207691982,46216.93,0.00631000,291.62882830,1640995200003,false,true
1207691983,46216.93,0.00443000,204.74099990,1640995200003,false,true
1207691984,46216.92,0.00573000,264.82295160,1640995200004,true,true
1207691985,46216.92,0.00718000,331.83748560,1640995200005,true,true

Note that I use uv to run the script.

The issue you're encountering is because sink_csv expects a file path as a string, not a file-like object like sys.stdout. Unfortunately, the sink_csv function in Polars doesn't support direct streaming to standard output as it expects a file path.
To work around this and stream the CSV to standard output, you can first collect the data into a DataFrame and then convert it to CSV. Here's how you can modify the script to achieve this:
import polars as pl
import sys

# Read Parquet file
df = pl.scan_parquet("BTCUSDT-trades-2022-01.parquet").collect()

# Write CSV data to stdout
df.write_csv(sys.stdout)


scan_parquet loads the Parquet file lazily.
collect forces the computation of the lazy frame, reading the data into a DataFrame.
write_csv writes the DataFrame content to standard output as CSV.

This approach resolves the issue and ensures you can stream the contents of a Parquet file to standard output as CSV text.

Wouldn't collect attempt to load the entire contents of the Parquet file into the DataFrame in memory?  My goal was to read and write the stream in blocks because each input file is quite large and there are twelve files for each year, so reading all of the the input data for a year would quickly consume all available memory in my laptop.
